# No remote URL configured for current branch project

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin

Why is eclipse giving me this "No remote URL configured for current branch project" error every 2 minutes?  It is triggered when the Yatta application request a project export, I assume.

Triggered by the de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.tasks plugin:

```
org.eclipse.team.core.TeamException: No remote URL configured for current branch in repository of project vaadinwebsite.
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProjectSetCapability.asReference(GitProjectSetCapability.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProjectSetCapability.asReference(GitProjectSetCapability.java:53)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.tasks.impl.ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskImpl.getProjectReference(ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:289)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.tasks.impl.ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskImpl.getProjectReference(ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskImpl.java:276)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.setup.internal.builders.ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskBuilder.addProjectReference(ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskBuilder.java:149)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.setup.internal.builders.ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskBuilder.build(ProfilesProjectSetImportTaskBuilder.java:133)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.setup.builders.core.SetupBuilder.buildTasks(SetupBuilder.java:290)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.oomph.setup.builders.core.SetupBuilder.buildTasks(SetupBuilder.java:233)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.client.export.ProfileExporter.createProfile(ProfileExporter.java:521)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.client.export.ProfileExporter.exportProfile(ProfileExporter.java:103)
    at de.yatta.eclipse.launcher.client.export.ExportJob.run(ExportJob.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

To the best of my knowledge, there is a remote URL for this project.  I mention "eclipse" and "yatta" only to give some context.  Considering the comments, it is probably more a "git" setup problem.

Comment: It says "for *current branch*" (emphasis mine), so presumably it's not willing to take a global repository-wide remote, it wants one specifically for the *current branch*. If there is only one remote, most likely named `origin`, presumably this means you should set the current branch's `remote` setting to `origin`.  If the current branch is `zorg` that would, on a command line, be `git config branch.zorg.remote origin`. What is in Eclipse I can't say.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. If you move your comment to "answer", I can mark it as the accepted answer. Or I can in a few days. Regardless, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's error message says "for *current branch*" (emphasis mine), so presumably it's not willing to take a global repository-wide remote: it wants one specifically for the current branch.  If there is only one remote, most likely named `origin`, presumably this means you should set the current branch's `remote` setting to `origin`.  If the current branch is `zorg` that would, on a command line, be `git config branch.zorg.remote origin`.  What commands to use, or clicky boxes to click on, in Eclipse, I cannot say.

This seems like a bug in Eclipse: Git in general will use `origin` when no remote is configured (e.g., if you run `git fetch` and the current branch has no configured remote, Git tries to fetch from `origin`).  Since Eclipse is its own thing, it can of course make its own rules, disregarding Git's in little ways like this, or even in major ways.

(Copied from comment to answer, with a bit of editorializing added :-) )